# How to setup trackPageview on the New Google Analytcis?

Tags: google-analytics

We've previously used Analytics with trackPageview like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/Step1']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

However, in the New Analytics, the script isn't formatted the same way and I'm a bit confused about how/where I should add back in the trackPageview code.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-1', 'page.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

So where in the new code should I put the "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/Step1']);" and in which format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start by reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) that is available for the new analytics.js library since it explains all of this.

Anyways, it looks like you're trying to [override the default value](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#overriding) for page views and set your own path. There is no _gaq or _trackPageview with the new analytics.js library. Instead, the equivalent code would be:

```
ga('create', 'UA-1');
ga('send', 'pageview', '/Step1');
```